# Grouping by one column and sorting by date

Tags: mysql, sql

Essentially, I am trying to group **customer names** and then sort by **transaction date** in **ASC order** and then only get the first two transactions (LIMIT 2)

```sql
SELECT 
    customer_names,
    transaction_date
FROM
    Customer
ORDER BY
    customer_names,
    transaction_date
LIMIT
    4
```

What would be this table w/o the `ORDER BY` and the `LIMIT`:

| customer_name | transaction_date |
| --- | --- |
| Jim | 1/1/22 |
| Jim | 3/1/22 |
| Pam | 1/2/22 |
| Dwight | 12/23/21 |
| Pam | 4/1/20 |
| Jim | 3/3/22 |
| Dwight | 1/1/22 |
| Pam | 8/1/22 |
| Dwight | 10/1/22 |

I would like it this way:

| customer_name | transaction_date |
| --- | --- |
| Dwight | 12/23/21 |
| Dwight | 1/1/22 |
| Jim | 1/1/22 |
| Jim | 3/1/22 |
| Pam | 4/1/20 |
| Pam | 1/2/22 |

Comment: You seem to be using MySQL. Are you using MySQL 5, MySQL 8, or MariaDB?

Comment: Your `Customer` table seems to be denormalized - what does `transaction-date` represent?

Comment: Yes, I am using MySQL 8. The transaction-date just a date in a string. By the way, thank you for editing.

Comment: You should fix that: always store dates/datetimes **as** `date` or `datetime`. [**Don't store dates/datetimes as strings**](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/422047/should-i-use-date-or-varchar-in-storing-dates-in-mysql). (bold shouty text for emphasi:, this is the number-one database design issue I come across and it's annoying because the root cause is either ignorance or laziness and I don't suffer either very well...)

Comment: I wish I could change it as well. Unfortunately, at the moment, it is a no-go...

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can ignore SQL's `GROUP BY` clause for this problem.

  - `GROUP BY` doesn't actually bunch rows into groups comprised of rows, instead think of it as the "`AGGREGATE BY`" clause instead.
- Instead, use *first* use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY customer_name ORDER BY transaction_date ASC )` to assign a relative ordinal to each row (`rn`).

  - Then filter by that such that `WHERE rn <= 2`, this will return the first two rows by `transaction-date` for each `customer_name`.
- As your `transaction_date` is a string using [the very silly American date format](https://deskthority.net/viewtopic.php?t=16007) you can't sort by it directly - you need to first parse it using `STR_TO_DATE( transaction_date, '%c/%e/%y' )`.

  - `'%c/%e/%y'` is MySQL's notation for `'M/d/yy'`.

Like so:

```sql
SET sql_mode = 'ANSI_QUOTES'; /* No way am I using backticks... */

WITH withParsedDate AS (
    SELECT
        customer_name,
        STR_TO_DATE( transaction_date, '%c/%e/%y' ) AS "date"
    FROM
        Customer
),
withRowNumber AS (
    SELECT
        customer_name,
        "date",
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY customer_name ORDER BY "date" ASC ) AS rn
    FROM
        withParsedDate
)
SELECT
    customer_name,
    "date",
    rn
FROM
    withRowNumber
WHERE
    rn <= 2;
```

this can be simplified to this:

```sql
SET sql_mode = 'ANSI_QUOTES'; /* No way am I using backticks... */

SELECT
    t2.customer_name,
    t2."date",
    t2.rn
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            c.customer_name,
            STR_TO_DATE( c.transaction_date, '%c/%e/%y' ) AS "date",
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY c.customer_name ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE( c.transaction_date, '%c/%e/%y' ) ASC ) AS rn
        FROM
            Customer AS c
    ) AS t2 
WHERE
    t2.rn <= 2;
```

Screenshot proof:

[image]

**Previous version:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This definitely helps me to know where I need to start from. If the transaction_date is in a different table, how much change will it need from what you provided?

Comment: It means you just need another `JOIN` somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
select  customer_name   
       ,str_to_date(transaction_date, '%m/%d/%Y') as transaction_date
from    (
         select *
               ,row_number() over(partition by customer_name order by str_to_date(transaction_date, '%m/%d/%Y')) as rn
         from   t
        ) t
where   rn <= 2
```

| customer_name | transaction_date |
| --- | --- |
| Dwight | 2021-12-23 00:00:00 |
| Dwight | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 |
| Jim | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 |
| Jim | 2022-03-01 00:00:00 |
| Pam | 2020-04-01 00:00:00 |
| Pam | 2022-01-02 00:00:00 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/egS6poGk?hide=2)

Comment: See updated answer.